# SharePoint Language Pack and My site

Tags: language

I made a small project on sharepoint 2010 in english, after some time, i installed the Portuguese (brazilian) language pack (pt-BR). When i go to My Site, the whole site is in the new language, except for the webpart titles, is there a way to change those titles to the new language, or do i have to change it manually?

Question about it, if it's not possible to change it now with all the profiles created, can i delete all the profiles and sync my profiles with my AD again and it re-create the sites? And if i do that, will it be in Portuguese?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing sounds like you are seeing a My Site created in english and where the pt-BR alternate language has been enabled and selected.  The SharePoint MUI does not handle webpart titles, so My Site, my profile, etc will be a mix of languages unless you are using a third party product like PointFire and enabling the feature on these sites.

You can follow these instructions http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362.aspx#configsettings to let users select the primary language of their My Site when they create it.  I have never tried to delete the profiles themselves, but I have tried to delete the individual My Site sites and the result wasn't good - it wouldn't re-create a new one after that and I stopped trying.